# Clearing Text widget with .delete("1.0",END) renders it unable to accept insertion of new text

Tags: python, tkinter, text

Python 3.8 Windows 10.
Created a Text object. Opened a file. Displayed the file. Cleared the text.
Now attempting to write again into textwidget fails.
Adding .configure(state="normal") doesn't help. How do you rewrite after clearing a Text widget ?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
txwdg = Text(root, bg= '#dec', fg= '#024' , font = ("Lucida  \     
      Console",11) , height = 34, width = 93 , spacing1 = 3, padx =4)
def Readfile() :  
    global ofile 
    ofile = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r',  \
              initialdir = "C:\\Users\\Chess\\Openings")
def Displayfile() :
    global ofile
    for item in ofile :
        txwdg.insert(INSERT,item)
def Clear() :
    txwdg.delete("1.0",END)
    # txwdg.configure(state = "normal")
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?  If there was an error message, we need to see the full traceback.  Does any other part of your code change the state of the Text widget?  If so, what state is it in when you call these functions?

Comment: Nothing will be read from the file if `Displayfile()` is called more than one because the file pointer is already at the end of the file.

Comment: Are you certain that you can't insert, or is it that you're not actually inserting anything? Have you verified that your loop `for item in ofile` is actually looping the second time it is called?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was the text **`file pointer`**. After displaying the file I added one line "ofile.seek(0)" , resetting the pointer to the beginning of the file. I was redisplaying the same file. Thanks for the answers.

```
def Displayfile() :
    global ofile
    for item in ofile :
        txwdg.insert(INSERT,item)
    ofile.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you dont provide a working example or errors all I can give you is a working example.

Maybe if you compare this to your code, you'll find your bug.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog


class App(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root: tkinter.Tk):
        super().__init__(root)
        root.title('display text file')
        root.geometry('700x450')
        root.resizable(False, False)

        self.text_widget = tkinter.Text(root)
        self.text_widget.pack()

        frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
        frame.pack(pady=20)

        tkinter.Button(frame, text='load file', command=self._load_file).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
        tkinter.Button(frame, text='clear', command=self._clear_text).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

    def _load_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfile()
        try:
            with open(file_path.name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
                self._write_file_to_widget(infile.readlines())
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def _write_file_to_widget(self, data: list):
        for line in data:
            self.text_widget.insert(tkinter.END, line)

    def _clear_text(self):
        self.text_widget.delete(1.0, tkinter.END)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```